# RDF file not uploaded in virtuoso

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I am trying to single upload an .rdf file to virtuoso with the `ld_dir` command, as follows:

```
ld_dir('/home', 'filename.rdf', 'http://domain.example/TEST');
```

The operation seems to be done, although it takes 1 msec; which is not logical.. however when I try to view the content of the grapgh using:

```
SELECT * FROM <http://domain.example/TEST> WHERE {?p ?o ?s}
```

it just does not display any results.
Performing the same query on another graph brings out results.

Comment: "Performing the same query on another graph brings out results." Another graph loaded in the same way? "The operation seems to be done, although it takes 1 msec"  I'd be surprised if there's a file named `/home` on a Unix-like system.  That's where the home directories are.  The documentation on [ld_dir](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_ld_dir.html) says that it loads all files matching the file mask.  (The example is `ld_dir ('/data8/2848260', '%.gz', 'http://bsbm.org');`.)  I bet you don't have any `/home/filename.rdf`, so it completes very quickly, but you see no data.

Answer (score 0):

[ld_dir](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_ld_dir.html) command will only bring RDF file's path into the awareness of Virtuoso. It won't make Virtuoso to start 'ingesting' the RDF file. Here are the commands to be typed inside isql console :

```
code ld_dir('/home', 'filename.rdf', 'http://domain.example/TEST');
set isolation='uncommitted';
rdf_loader_run();
```

It is the `rdf_loader_run();` command which does the trick. And this command took lots of time (already running since few minutes) on my machine - than just 1ms

Source [The complete tutorial on RDF data ingestion in Virtuoso](https://confluence.deri.ie:8443/display/webstar/The+complete+tutorial+for+RDF+data+ingestion+in+Virtuoso)